# In $V^3$ are given four vectors, check, depending on parameters, if they generate $V^3$ and choose parameters so that some linear spans are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

In $V^3$ ($V^3$ is a vector space, 3-dimesional plane over the field of real numbers) are given four vectors $$\vec{x} = \vec{j} + \vec{k}$$ $$\vec{y} = \vec{i} + \vec{k}$$ $$\vec{z} = a\vec{i} + a\vec{j} + \vec{k}$$ $$\vec{v} = \vec{i} + \vec{j} + b\vec{k}$$
a) Depending on parameters a  $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ , determine if set ($\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z}, \vec{v}$) generates $V^3$

b) Determin, if it exist, parameter  $a\in\mathbb{R}$  so that it is satisfied: $\operatorname{span}\{\vec{x},\vec{x} + \vec{y}\} = \operatorname{span}\{\vec{y},\vec{z}\}$

I know when certain set generates a vector space, and when two spans are equal, but this representation of vectors is weird to me and I don't know how to proceed

Comment: You could translate this problem in terms of matrices with columns being the coordinates. Then (a) is about when the matrice is of full rank and (b) is about when two matrices have the same column space.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more?

Comment: What about this representation of vectors do you find "weird"? What is the representation you're more familiar with? This is how vectors are introduced to students in high-school physics in the first place (3-dimensional real coordinate space with the unit basis vectors $\vec i,\vec j,\vec k$ along the positive $x,y,z$-axes respectively). You can identify $V^3$ defined here with the vector space $\Bbb R^3(\Bbb R)$ over the field $\Bbb R$ with the canonical basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ if that is more comfortable to you.